# Python - reading the returnURL

Tags: python, paypal

I'm using python without a server to deploy to. Im trying to test the accept payment flow for Paypal.

In the code after sending a POST request I store the result into a local file and then open this file using "webbrowser".

However I suspect that I am missing something here since once I log in as a user I'm not automatically redirected to authorize the transaction but rather just log in.

Now I suspect this is because once I hit the Payment API endpoint it is redirecting me to the login API with some parameters

```
http://www.paypal.com?hypotheticalredirecturl=etc
```

Now I am capturing the response i.e - the html of the paypal login page. However the whole 
URL cannot be captured. Hence the part

```
hypotheticalredirecturl=etc
```

cannot be captured and I think that this is stopping the flow from going to the

authorization page after I log in as a user.

I think if I appended the "hypotheticalredirect" part to my webpage after opening it using "webbrowser" I might be able make the flow normal.

Does any one know of any way to capture the url of the response?

I tried looking into the page itself but I dont think its there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashwin

**EDIT** : Using urllib and urllib2. Should I be looking at httplib?

Comment: Researching it further I think urllib.response.geturl() might be helpful.